# sklearn LogisticRegression - plot displays too small coefficient

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am attempting to fit a logistic regression model to sklearn's iris dataset. I get a probability curve that looks like it is too flat, aka the coefficient is too small.  I would expect a probability over ninety percent by sepal length > 7 :

[image]

Is this probability curve indeed wrong?  If so, what might cause that in my code?

```
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

data = datasets.load_iris()

#get relevent data
lengths = data.data[:100, :1]
is_setosa = data.target[:100]         

#fit model
lgs = LogisticRegression()
lgs.fit(lengths, is_setosa)
m = lgs.coef_[0,0]
b = lgs.intercept_[0]

#generate values for curve overlay
lgs_curve = lambda x: 1/(1 + math.e**(-(m*x+b)))         
x_values = np.linspace(2, 10, 100)
y_values = lgs_curve(x_values)

#plot it
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.scatter(lengths, is_setosa, c='r', s=2)
plt.xlabel("Sepal Length")
plt.ylabel("Probability is Setosa")
```

Comment: What wrong about the curve? It looks good to me. Stick to [ask] and be specific about what you get and in how far it does not meet your expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I just edited it to try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression, you will find a regularization parameter `C` that can be passed as argument while training the logistic regression model.

> C : float, default: 1.0 Inverse of regularization strength; must be a
>   positive float. Like in support vector machines, smaller values
>   specify stronger regularization.

Now, if you try different values of this ***regularization*** parameter, you will find that larger values of `C` leads to fitting curves that has sharper transitions from 0 to 1 value of the output (response) binary variable, and still larger values fit models that have high variance (try to model the training data transition more closely, i think that's what you are expecting, then you may try to set `C` value as high as `10` and plot) but at the same time are likely to have the risk to ***overfit***, while the default value `C=1` and values smaller than that lead to high bias and are likely to ***underfit*** and here comes the famous ***bias-variance trade-off*** in machine learning.

You can always use techniques like *cross-validation* to choose the `C` value that is right for you. The following code / figure shows the probability curve fitted with models of different complexity (i.e., with different values of the regularization parameter `C`, from `1` to `10`):

```
x_values = np.linspace(2, 10, 100)
x_test = np.reshape(x_values, (100,1))

C = list(range(1, 11))
labels = map(str, C)
for i in range(len(C)): 
    lgs = LogisticRegression(C = C[i]) # pass a value for the regularization parameter C
    lgs.fit(lengths, is_setosa)
    y_values = lgs.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1] # use this function to compute probability directly
    plt.plot(x_values, y_values, label=labels[i])

plt.scatter(lengths, is_setosa, c='r', s=2)
plt.xlabel("Sepal Length")
plt.ylabel("Probability is Setosa")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

## Predicted probs with models fitted with different values of `C`

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, thanks!  What can I set C to if I want no regularization?  (I realize that will add to reduced test accuracy, but this is more of a theoretical exercize for me)

Comment: To a high value, may be you can try 10, 100, 1000 etc. (Ideally infinity) but values such as 100 or 1000 should serve the purpose I think.

Answer (score 0):

Although you do not describe what you want to plot, I assume you want to plot the separating line. It seems that you are confused with respect to the Logistic/sigmoid function. The decision function of Logistic Regression is a line.

Comment: I am plotting the probability that an iris is type Setosa based on Sepal Length.  This probability comes from fitting a model to the data points (in red).  The probability function is a sigmoid function.

Answer (score 0):

Your probability graph looks flat because you have, in a sense, "zoomed in" too much.

If you look at the middle of a sigmoid function, it get's to be almost linear, as the second derivative get's to be almost 0 (see for example a [wolfram alpha graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F(1%2Be%5E(-x)))%27%27%20between%20-1%20and%201))

Please note that the value's we are talking about are the results of `-(m*x+b)`

When we reduce the limits of your graph, say by using
`x_values = np.linspace(4, 7, 100)`, we get something which looks like a line:
[image]

But on the other hand, if we go crazy with the limits, say by using `x_values = np.linspace(-10, 20, 100)`, we get the clearer sigmoid:
[image]

Comment: I see what you say about adjusting x axis limits.  However doesn't it seem wrong to you that at sepal length > 7 my probability is still below 80%?  That is what is confusing me.